# Zoomstack loading in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis

Does anyone know of a way that you can style OS Zoomestack and order the layers so that each time it is inserted in QGIS 3 it styles automatically and in the correct order?

Comment: What is Zoomestack?

Comment: spelling mistake but Zoomstack is OS opendata.